# Get time using latitude and longitude in php

Tags: php, time, latitude-longitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timezone lookup from latitude longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude)
>   [PHP IF Statment Based On Geo Location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004294/php-if-statment-based-on-geo-location)

How should I get the exact time of a location using it's latitude and longitude?

Comment: Googling `Get time using latitude and longitude in php` gives a lot of good hits for me, for example [Get PHP Timezone Name from Latitude and Longitude?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3126878)

Comment: @Bolaji  , Bawoni ??? use `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=29.488899230957,-98.398696899414` after you get long , lat you also nee api keys :)  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/